# Is it possible to use "infinite Scrolling" in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm in the process of analyzing the requirement. Is it possible to use "infinite scrolling" in React ? I am using ToolkitProvider with Bootstrap Table.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this?  https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-infinite-scroll

Comment: Thanks Nathan. Yes, functionality wise you're right. But, in our APP, we use Toolkitprovider and Bootstraptable to show data in a Grid format. I would want to check if Infinite scrolling can be added to the existing functionality. For example, i'm using paging option by implementing PageFactory. I'm new to React. The UI implementation is based on functional components.